# How to show all bandwidth in adaptive bandwitdh KDE?

Tags: distributions, kernel, smoothing

I have implemented the KDE distribution finding for a dataset. I apply the adaptive bandwidth method; I want to plot the change in bandwidth over the entire distribution. How can I do it? Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you the adaptive bandwidths that *Mathematica* uses:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 10] // Sort;

α = 0.6;
kmd = KernelMixtureDistribution[data, {"Adaptive", Automatic, α}];
bw = kmd[[2, 4]]
(* {0.455945, 0.367787, 0.354622, 0.350731, 0.340984, 0.33284, 0.335444, 0.336422,
    0.343412, 0.517947}{0.455945, 0.367787, 0.354622, 0.350731, 0.340984, 0.33284,
    0.335444, 0.336422, 0.343412, 0.517947} *)
```

However, these bandwidths do not match what R gives (using `akj` in the `quantreg` package) which is the same as I get doing this in *Mathematica* with a brute force method.  I'll look at that more to see if I can figure out the difference.

One can then plot those adaptive bandwidths against the data values:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{data, bw}], Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"Data value", "Adaptive bandwidth"}]
```

[image: Data values vs adaptive bandwidth]

Comment: Can also use `kmd["Weights"]`  to get  the list `kmd[[2, 4]]` (+1)

Comment: @kglr `kmd["Weights"]` seems to get `kmd[[2,1]]`.  And maybe those weights might help explain the difference I get using R.

Comment: sorry, I meant `kmd["Bandwidth"]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved it